# Magento2 - Override Template order summary in sales email order

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.1

I have the template that is using the following to render order summary

> {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order
>   area="frontend"}}

it is taking the code from the following template

> /app/design/frontend/Corra/Mytheme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

So I want to override this file with my custom module file and use this one.

I created a module "**Corra_Sales**"

I put the .phtml here

> /app/code/Corra/Sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

Also, I created the layout with the file:

> /app/code/Corra/Sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml

The code inside file is:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" as="default" template="Corra_Sales::email/items/order/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also, I tried with :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Corra_Sales::email/items/order/default.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I clear cache, remove var folder, rebuild, etc.

But it still not working, someone could tell me what I am doing wrong that always take this file ->?

> /app/design/frontend/Corra/Mytheme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml

Comment: As it is said in the official documentation (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html) - "Theme templates override module templates"

Comment: If you could explain why are you trying to accomplish this, maybe we could figure something out

Comment: @AleksandrasGavinčiuk I need to show custom functionality in the template but I can not modify the template on the design that why I've created a new module.

Comment: Why can't you modify the one in the theme folder? You actually need to overwrite it or you can add your functionality in another template?

Comment: Why can't you modify the one in the theme folder? Because it is a requirement of the client :S 
You actually need to overwrite it or you can add your functionality in another template? I need to override the file described above.

Comment: Could you create a child theme and overwrite it there?

Comment: is this issue got resolved? If yes, please provide us the solution

Comment: No, this issue was not resolved. By now I changed on template.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me under 2.2.5 your module file needs to state the sequence to follow Vendor/ModuleExample/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ModuleExample" setup_version="1.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

You also need to take into consideration that the block does not have a name, so you might want to use the alias.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" as="default" template="Vendor_ModuleExample::email/items/order/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Let me know if it helped.

Sources:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177343/override-magento-2-email-items-order-default-phtml 
https://www.classyllama.com/blog/template-override-m2